# Gas expansion during phase change (intense boiling) relation to liquid level rasing to overboiling level of a container (Literature?)

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, phase-transition, evaporation

I'm looking into the area of "slugging" in open-containers which are containing a pure substance undergoing a phase-change from liquid->Vapor. **I'm trying to find a connection between rapid heat transfer into the liquid-vapor mixture and the situation of "over-boiling" where liquid is expelled from the container cause by the rapid expansion of vapor.** The phenomenon occurs like if a kettle is filled over the recommended limit and the boiling makes it expel hot liquid water with the steam.

I have not been able to find any research papers or other engineering fields/literature where this relation is addressed. In thermodynamics if you are dealing with a saturated liquid-vapor mixture you can treat them as a homogeneous mixture for simplification, and with the knowledge of the quality one can figure out what volume the vapor and liquid is taking up in a container, but it can not be used for looking into the specific dynamic of the phase-change.

I'm looking for any information either literature or keywords (for searching) which either is looking into this field specifically or can point me in a direction which might help answer my question.

- Any relation to boiling affecting the mixture liquid level
- Any relation to the rapid boiling resulting in the expulsion of liquid

I know this is a complex subject but any help is appreciated.

Example of water level effected by boiling: https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxjCIXDxSVDPqr4tklgZ5YCqpQ_FJehP8q

Slugging occurring in a boiler: https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxJRBAYDrVN7jUojYVT_ZJTJNspyAtLeJU
(The effect is similar to my problem just with a low pressure suction assisting the removeal of non-vapor material)

Comment: But there are thousands of papers on the phenomenon of slug flow boiling, include characterization of the vapor volume. What part is unclear? If you’re asking about liquid expulsion from a certain container that can’t accommodate both the liquid and the vapor volume, that’s more of an engineering question, I should think.

Answer (score 0):

This is the domain of *superheat kinetics* which is treated in any decent text on boiling heat transfer. It also is the province of *thermal inkjet device physics*; about which there is some scientific literature. Search for keywords "Hewlett-Packard", "thermal inkjet", and author names Ross R. Allen and William R. Knight.